# Is there a way to check if an incomplete row matches with a complete row and then update it?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table in SQL with data that is malformed.

Here's the table:

| rep_id | first | last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evanz" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 |  |  |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |

As you can see in the first, sixth, and eighth rows there is data that is clearly inputted incorrectly. Is there a way to update those rows to match the others? I assume you would have to group by the count of correct rows then determine that the bad rows are "close enough". Then you would set each value to the correct value? I know how to set values in tables, but I don't know how to make a rule that works for any table...

Would like it to change to:

| rep_id | first | last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |
| 1 | "Jason" | "Evans" |

Comment: Please no images. Show us sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data are not useful.

Comment: alright I think I simplified the question and wrote the table out. @Stu

Comment: I changed those things you asked for @jarlh

Comment: This can be done, but I can't stop wondering why you store the same row of data over and over again. Wouldn't it be better with just one row, and you can add a count column too - if it's of importance to know there are 13 (1, Jason, Evans).

Comment: This is still confusing, you have a difference in all 3 columns so how do you know which to 'group'? How is the row with rep_id X part of this "group" and not another group? There are so many edge cases for this logic.

Comment: I just used part of the whole table to make it simpler, I couldn't fit the whole table in the question. I'm just wondering If sql can recognize and fill the missing data. @jarlh

Comment: the grouping was just an idea if I were to try and figure this out. I'm mostly trying to learn how sql can read data and "correct" it. @Stu